# I want to create a new string out of prefix of one string and suffix of another

Tags: c

I have 2 strings: A and B.

```
A = "cat"
B = "dog"
```

What I want is to take prefix from the first string, and suffix from the other.

`C = "cg"`

and to write out all of the combinations:

```
cg
cog
cdog
cag
caog
cadog
catg
catog
catdog
```

and print out a total number of possible combinations `n = 9`.

here's what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


main(){

    FILE * f;
    f = fopen("nova.txt","r");


    char a[100];
    char b[100];

    fscanf(f,"%s",&a);
    fscanf(f,"%s",&b);

    int a_d = strlen(a);
    int b_d = strlen(b);


    char nova[a_d*b_d][a_d+b_d];
    int i,j,k,l;

    for(i = 0; i < a_d; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < b_d; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < a_d; k++)
                nova[a_d*b_d][a_d+b_d] = a[k];
            for(l = b_d; l > 0; l--)
                nova[a_d*b_d][a_d+b_d] = b[l];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<strlen(nova);i++){
        printf("%s",nova);
    }


}
```

here's my `nova.txt` file:

```
cat
dog
```

EDIT:

current output:

```
e
```

Comment: what do you expect this to do : `nova[20][9] = a[k];` ?

Comment: Why do you parse the same thing twice?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It was by a mistake. I have edited it. I meant to use nova[strlen(a)*strlen(b)][strlen(a)+strlen(b)]

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah, But I have declared `nova` to be able to hold a sum of `a` and `b`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker `nova[20][9] = a[k] ` I expect it to move characters from `a` string to this new `nova` string

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have fixed it.

Comment: @MareGraphicsMaRe regarding `nova[20][9] = a[k]`, this way you're putting a `char` in a specific point of `nova`, always the same place at each cycle, that is row `20`, column `9` if you imagine your array as a matrix.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oooh, so I should Use a variable from a for loop above. Let me try it.

Comment: @MareGraphicsMaRe : in that case, you're probably best off to read up on how arrays work in C, and specifically on how to put specific values at specific offsets in an array. Eg. : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: I get an error trying to compile your code, where you do `strlen(nova)`, because `nova` is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the following program to meet your requirements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "cat";
    char *str2 = "dog";
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    char *str3 = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    int prefix, suffix;
    
    for (prefix = 0; prefix < len1; prefix++)
    {
        /* Reset the string. */
        memset(str3, 0, sizeof(str3));
        
        /* Copy the prefix. */
        memcpy(str3, str1, (prefix + 1));
        
        for (suffix = len2 - 1; suffix >= 0; suffix--)
        {
            /* Manually concatincate the suffix. */
            memcpy((str3 + prefix + 1), (str2 + suffix), (len2 - suffix));
            
            /* Print the current combination. */
            printf("%s\r\n", str3);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
cg 
cog
cdog
cag
caog
cadog
catg
catog
catdog
```

Comment: Good solution; shouldn't the `malloc` be +1?

Comment: @NeilEdelman If this answer helped you, please up vote it and mark it correct.

Comment: I'm not the one that asked the original question, but +1 for the edit.